# Using MySQL with Rails 3.0

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to configure my rails application with MySQL. When start my application, i get this error

**Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/opt/local/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock**

I have installed rails in /opt/local/bin/rails folder.

MySQL is installed in /usr/local/mysql/ folder

What do I need to do to make this work?

Thanks.

Comment: This sounds like either your database.yml file isn't configured right or the mysql server is not running.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to find out where your socket is.  If you have a mac it is normally /tmp/mysql.sock.  then go into your config/database.yml file and change the socket.

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: your_db
  username: root
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

Good luck.